# Can only read once from PIC16's RCO port

Tags: c, pic, microchip

Been searching for an answer for this for a few days now.  I'm trying to create this simple verification program where if I push a button it drives the voltage on `RC0` to 5 volts, and when the button is unpushed, a pulldown resistor pulls the pin down to 0.  The problem is, the code will only work the first time I push the button.  After that it will not enter the `if (RC0 == 1)` loop.   Here is my code snippet.  What am I missing here?

```
void main(void){
    /* Configure the oscillator for the device */
    ConfigureOscillator();

    /* Initialize I/O and Peripherals for application */
    InitApp();

    TRISB = 0x0F;         // turn on RB7 for use as output
    TRISC = 0xFF;         //  turn on RC0 for use as input
    ANSEL = 0b11101111;   //  use RC0 as digital input
    unsigned char time = 0;

    while (1) {
        //delay for 10 seconds
        if (PORTCbits.RC0 == 1) {
            while (time < 10) {
                /* TODO */
                RB7 = 1;
                __delay_ms(100);

                RB7 = 0;
                __delay_ms(100);
                time++;
            }
        }

        if (PORTCbits.RC0 == 0){ //This if statement will always execute when 
                                 //RC0 == 0, but will not execute when I push 
                                 //the button.  This really confuses me.  
                                 //Can RCO be given a value different than 1?
            __delay_ms(2000);
        }

        RB7 = 0;
        __delay_ms(500);
        RB7 = 1;
        __delay_ms(500);

    }

}
```

Comment: Nevermind!  Just figured it out after rereading through my post.  I never changed the time variable back to 0 to enter the loop again.